# GDB fails to run due to python path issue. How do I set the PYTHONPATH and PYTHON_LIBRARY?

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS Code to debug and write C++ on a remote compute cluster. If I have the Anaconda module loaded then when I run GDB I get the following error

`ImportError: No module named site`

If I run GDB with the following command it works fine

```
PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/python2.7 
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/python2.7:/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib
dynload:/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages gdb
```

How do I add these paths to the `launch.json` config? I've already tried just adding those paths to PYTHONPATH or PYTHON_LIBRARY but if I do that then I break ipython which I use regularly.